# Giving right answer for N = 2000000 but not passing test cases

Tags: c#

Find the sum of all prime numbers not greater than N. For example if user input 5 then prime numbers are 2,3,5 and their sum is 10. It is not passing 4 test cases in which two of them are exceeding the time limit. I have tried several test cases and my code is working fine on them. Here is my code.

```
public static long sieve_of_eratosthenes(long n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        // If the user input 1.
        return (0);
    }
    else
    {
        long sum = 0;
        bool[] array = new bool[n + 1];
        for (long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            // Setting all values to true.
            array[i] = true;                        
        }
        // Eliminating the composite numbers.
        for (long j = 2; j < Math.Sqrt(n); j++)            
        {
            if (array[j])
            {
                long multiple = 1;
                for (long k = (j * j); k <= n; k = (j * j) + (j * (multiple++)))
                {
                    array[k] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //Now we have the prime numbers. We just have to add them.
        for (int z = 2; z <= n; z++)
        {
            if (array[z])
            {
                sum = sum + z;
            }
        }
        return (sum);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int noofcases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for( int i = 0; i < noofcases; i ++)
    {
        long entry = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(sieve_of_eratosthenes(entry));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic might work, but it is far from efficient. The usage of arrays is unnecessary here, just do the check for a prime-number in a for-loop and calculate the sum while doing it instead of using such huge arrays to store your results inbetween. This clogs your memory and massively hurts your performance.

Comment: i only find Sieve's method for finding the prime numbers that's why i use arrays. can you please elaborate the method you are talking about.

Comment: I suspect there is a rounding issue with the SQRT method : j < Math.Sqrt(n)  Try rounding up using Celing method.

Comment: It didn't make any difference in the outcome. @jdweng

Comment: You can speed up algorithm by eliminating all even numbers except 2.  : int z = 3; z <= n; z += 2 and long j = 3; j < Math.Sqrt(n); j += 2

Comment: Tested your algorithm up to 100,000,000. Seems to be correct, albeit a bit convoluted. E.g., the inner loop can be simplified to `for (long k = j * j; k <= n; k += j)`

Answer (score 2):

check the below code. I wrote simple logic which you can improve

```
public static class Int32Extension
{
    public static bool IsPrime(this int number)
    {
        if (number <= 1) return false;
        if (number == 2) return true;
        if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

        var boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

        for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
            if (number % i == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input;)
    {
        if (!(++i).IsPrime())
            continue;

        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

---

Without using Extension Method

```
public static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number <= 1) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

    var boundary = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number));

    for (int i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input = 5;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input;)
    {
        if (!IsPrime(++i))
            continue;

        sum += i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

.Net Fiddle Link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEBY9r

Edit : The IsPrime test uses [Primality Test With Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode)

Comment: Thanks for helping, it looks like good code, but I feel it's probably not what the Op needs. It uses advanced language features like extensions and it doesn't help him to learn the basics. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: thanks for the answer. but can you tell me the logic of the boundary variable. i will be very thankful for yours.

Comment: check the included reference